# scipy\sparse\csr.pyc in asindices(x) get IndexError: invalid index

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I am using a lib [UnbalancedDataset](https://github.com/fmfn/UnbalancedDataset) to do some oversampling.

I have `X_train_features.shape` (30962, 15637) and `y_train.shape`  (30962,)

`type(X_train_features)` is `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix`

get index error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-fa5e3a9ff626> in <module>()
      5 os = OverSampler(ratio=ratio, verbose=verbose)
      6 
----> 7 osx, osy = os.fit_transform(X_train_features, y_train)

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\unbalanceddataset-0.1-py2.7.egg\unbalanced_dataset\unbalanced_dataset.pyc in fit_transform(self, x, y)
    260 
    261         self.fit(x, y)
--> 262         self.out_x, self.out_y = self.resample()
    263 
    264         return self.out_x, self.out_y

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\unbalanceddataset-0.1-py2.7.egg\unbalanced_dataset\over_sampling.pyc in resample(self)
     52 
     53         # Start with the majority class
---> 54         overx = self.x[self.y == self.maxc]
     55         overy = self.y[self.y == self.maxc]
     56 

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csr.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
    305             row, col = self._index_to_arrays(row, col)
    306 
--> 307         row = asindices(row)
    308         col = asindices(col)
    309         if row.shape != col.shape:

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csr.pyc in asindices(x)
    224                     x = x.astype(idx_dtype)
    225             except:
--> 226                 raise IndexError('invalid index')
    227             else:
    228                 return x

IndexError: invalid index
```

I debug into the lib, and find `self.x[self.y == self.maxc]` is equal to

```
X_train_features[y_train == 1]
```

1. I guess that this statement is to select all `y_train == 1` row in `X_train_features`, ins't it?
2. how to overcome this error?

Comment: There's already an [issue](https://github.com/fmfn/UnbalancedDataset/issues/26) open for this. Wait for the maintainer, or try to debug it yourself.

Comment: @toasted_flakes the issue is I opened...and I post this question is trying to solve it my self. The issue is just tell the owner maybe his lib has a bug.

Comment: Oh I hadn't realized it was you. Good luck then :)

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
X_train_features[y_train == 1]
```

work?  With small samples this sort of indexing works:

```
In [225]: M=sparse.csr_matrix(np.arange(12).reshape(3,4))
In [226]: M[np.arange(3)>0]
```

Comment: `X_train_features[y_train == 1]` doesn't work too, with the error I post  the question.

Comment: Does my small sample work?  Or any thing else using a boolean mask to index a `csr` matrix?

Comment: Your sample works.Because I am not familiar with matrix manipulation and poor knowledge about the proper noun in the area of mathematics(a non-native speaker). What' is `any thing else using a boolean mask to index a csr matrix` means?

Comment: There's something about your arrays that either doesn't fit your description, or doesn't fit the libraries expectations.  So when the developer responds to the issue be prepared to give them actual examples.